# Process gets killed in Linux over ssh connection with putty

Tags: java, linux

I have a program in java which needs to be compiled and run over ssh on other machine. The program takes less than `512MB`.

However when i run this program on linux(over ssh connection), my process gets killed.

The program release the memory in following way once it has computed result from these values:\

`setSparseMatrix(new SparseMatrix(n))`

I think java garbage collector can automatically regain this memory since no pointer exist to that old matrix.

**Additional information:**

I tested this program in eclipse and it runs easily on pc with ram `512 MB`.

One more thing it works sometimes and sometimes it does not.\

so can someone tell me how can i see the reason that my program gets killed?

Comment: *I think java garbage collector can automatically regain this memory since no pointer exist to that old matrix.* What do you think that *`setSparseMatrix`* does?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think it creates a new matrix and once it has done that then there is no pointer to the older matrix then memory occupied by the older matrix should be regained!

Comment: You may be right. We wouldn't know. You didn't post it.

Comment: Could you furthermore post some parameters used to start the Application? (Heap, used GC,...). Have you already looked into the logs of the App, GC logs? Stuff like that would be my first entry for a deeper analysis.

Comment: @triplem that i am asking , how can i see the logs?What are the commands?

Comment: You should know what files are the log files. Use `less` to view those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is probably getting killed the moment you disconnect your SSH connection from putty.

You should run your Java process with a `nohup` command.

So something like: `nohup java <the rest of your command line> &` would make sure that your process does not hang up and die when your SSH command dies and the terminal sends SIG-HUP to it, and `&` makes it run in the background.

You might want to pipe the standard output of your program to some log file, in case you want to check what its output is.

Comment: i do not disconnect connection from putty but the program takes arround 99 minutes to solve the problem and with `nohup` i get `nohup:ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out`

Comment: Yeah with nohup if you dont do anything it will write output to `nohup.out`, thats normal.